# Find sum of ASCII value in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm new for Spark and Hive. I would like to calculate the summation of ASCII value in column "name" in Hive Table.

So in Hive, it has ascii() built-in function but it returns value only for first character. Does Hive provide the loop function to iterate all chars in name?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing a loop in hiveql, can you not create the table as external table. And then directly loop through the specific column, converting it to ascii.
You can still query the new ascii column using hiveql. And modify that data in the file using java/python. Thats the beauty of hive and schema-on-read.

Comment: I did this one already and it's working find than making the query directly from Hive. Thanks!